# Sending compressed stream over websocket, where and how it is supported?

Tags: node.js, websocket, gzip

I know that there are ready to use solutions like socket.io for sending data over websocket using compression.

But I can not find in which browsers/versions compression is supported and in which way it works.

I want to send a binary file in a stream from nodejs server, then on a browser side decompress it using stream (for example each megabyte will be compressed using gzip on a server, then when delivered decompressed on a browser side and start processing before a whole file will received). There is such or similar solution, and what currently natively supported by browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at pako? It reports to work in browsers.

https://github.com/nodeca/pako

Comment: Wow, really looks like what I need, i will check it.

Comment: It is not native compression, it is javascript pollify, i need native for both speed and memory.

Comment: If you're trying to have something native in a browser, you're probably out of luck, as browsers only understand JavaScript anymore (unless you write browser plugins). Javascript is compiled to be very close to native. You might be surprised at how fast it will work.